# Is there way to change the format of date in the date filter in ag grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, date-format, ag-grid-react, datefilter

I am using date filter in my AGGrid. My application is built using React. I need to set a custom format in the date filter. For example : Here it is mm/dd/yyyy and I need to use DD MMM YYYY. Is there a solution available?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

No readily available solution found.

Comment: No solutions found? Javascript has a builtin object, `Date()`